# Detail view during using bootstrap-table not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table library working with jQuery.
I need to show a few details in each rows, it has a function for doing this. 
I check everything, but still not working.

It has an attribute should be inserted in :

```
    data-detail-view="true"
    data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
```

I copy and paste my code here:

```js
function detailFormatter(index, row) {
  var html = [];
  $.each(row, function(key, value) {
    html.push('<p><b>' + key + ':</b>' + value + '</p>');
  });
  return html.join('');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>



<table class="treat-table" id="table" data-detail-view="true" data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="5" data-search="true" data-show-footer="false">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="checkboxselect" data-checkbox="true"></th>
      <th data-field="id" data-width="40" data-halign="center">ID</th>
      <th data-sortable="true" data-width="150" data-field="category" data-searchable="true">Category</th>
      <th data-field="treatmentName" data-width="200" data-searchable="true">Treatment Name</th>
      <th data-field="treatmentPrice">Treatment price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td data-halign="center">2</td>
      <td data-searchable="true">Plastic surgery</td>
      <td data-searchable="true">Rhino plasty</td>
      <td>range: $2000 to 3000$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td data-halign="center">2</td>
      <td data-searchable="true">Plastic surgery</td>
      <td data-searchable="true">Lift > Face lift</td>
      <td>range: $2000 to 3000$</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

but it is not working and do not change anything in my table, I also found that an error in my phpstorm about the function "detailFormatter"
not using in the page, but I use it as like as I explained above. 
my actual result should be like this link : [Example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#options/detail-view.html)

Comment: you forgot to include boostrap libs.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code into this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/bapewft2/2/

your code is good and suppose to work. the only problem i think is in your `css` and `script` at the top you have reference url's that starts with `//` instead of a valid protocol like `http://` or `https://`.

so make sure to change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.13.2/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
```